# Что значит данная запись в CSS?

Tags: css

Что значит данная запись в CSS?

```
div[class^=col]
```

И насколько это кроссбраузерно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это означает `div` с классом, начинающимся с указанного текста `col`. 
`.col1`, `.column`, `.col-12` попадают под селектор.

Это довольно старая инструкция, у нее [отличная кроссбраузерность](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel2)

Answer (score 4):

**Значение атрибута начинается с определённого текста**

> Устанавливает стиль для элемента в том случае, если значение атрибута
>   тега начинается с указанного текста. Синтаксис применения следующий.

```
[атрибут^="значение"] { Описание правил стиля } 
Селектор[атрибут^="значение"] { Описание правил стиля }
```

> В первом случае стиль применяется ко всем элементам, у которых
>   значение атрибута начинаются с указанного текста. А во втором — только
>   к определённым селекторам. Использование кавычек не обязательно, но
>   только если значение содержит латинские буквы и без пробелов.

Пример:

```css
a[href^="http://"] { 
  font-weight: bold /* Жирное начертание */
 }
```

```html
<p><a href="1.html">Обычная ссылка</a> | 
  <a href="http://htmlbook.ru" target="_blank">Внешняя 
  ссылка на сайт htmlbook.ru</a></p>
```

Внешние ссылки начинающиеся с ключевого слова `http://` будут выделены жирным начертанием.

[Источник](http://htmlbook.ru/samcss/selektory-atributov)

P.S: [там же](http://htmlbook.ru/samcss/selektory-atributov) и о других селекторах атрибутов.

Answer (score 3):

`[attr^="val"]` означает, что выбрать элемент, атрибут которого начинается с val, например "value".

У вас значит выбрать `div` у которого `class` начинается с *col*

На сколько кроссбраузерно можно посмотреть на всеизвестном ресурсе [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3)

В частности получается так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В целом селекторы можно посмотреть на [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)